# How to save large float into TFRecord format? float_list/float32 seems to truncate the values

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

We write processed data into TFRecords and we are noticing data loss when read back from TFRecords. Reproducible example below. Strange thing is that it doesn't just drop the decimals but seem to randomly roundup/down values. Since it only allows float32, int64 and string, we are not sure what other options to try.

**We are writing these values**

[20191221.1, 20191222.1, 20191223.1, 20191224.1, 20191225.1, 20191226.1, 20191227.1, 20191228.1, 20191229.1, 20191230.1]

**But reading from tfrecords returns these values**

tf.Tensor(
[20191222. 20191222. 20191224. 20191224. 20191226. 20191226. 20191228.
 20191228. 20191230. 20191230.], shape=(10,), dtype=float32)

**Reproducible Code**

```
import tensorflow as tf

def write_date_tfrecord():  
    #writes 10 dummy values to replicate the issue
    data = [20191221.1 + x for x in range(0,10)]
    print("Writing data - ", data)

    example = tf.train.Example(
            features = tf.train.Features(
                feature = {                    
                    'data':tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=data))                    
                     }
                ))


    writer = tf.io.TFRecordWriter("data.tf_record")
    writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

def parse_function(serialized_example):
        features = {
            'data': tf.io.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.float32,allow_missing=True) 
             }
        features = tf.io.parse_single_example(serialized=serialized_example, features=features)  
        data = features['data']
        return data

def dataset_generator():
    trRecordDataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset("data.tf_record")
    trRecordDataset = trRecordDataset.map(parse_function, num_parallel_calls = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    return trRecordDataset


if __name__ == '__main__':
    write_date_tfrecord()
    generator = dataset_generator()
    for data in generator:
        print(data)
```

Comment: did you found a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. We ended up changing the format to account for this random loss.

Answer (score 2):

This solved my issue. I had this issue when writing audio files as floating point matrix using FloatList.. but when i used BytesList and stored the data into tfrecords and then read the data by decoding it.. the issue resolved.. note that even decoding with tf.float32 will lead not solve the issue. we need to decode it with tf.float64..

```
def _bytes_feature2(value):
     return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def serialize_example(sound):
  feature = {
      'snd': _bytes_feature2(sound.tobytes()),
  }
  example_proto = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
  return example_proto.SerializeToString()

def write_tfrecords(rf,snd):
    nsamples = len(snd)
    with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(rf) as writer:
        for i in range(nsamples):
            SND = snd[i]
            tf_example = serialize_example(SND)
            writer.write(tf_example)

# writing records
write_tfrecords(os.getcwd()+'\\tfrec\\'+'train.tfrecords',train)

# loading records
raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(os.getcwd()+'\\tfrec\\'+'train.tfrecords')

def parse_record(record):
  name_to_features= {
      'snd':tf.io.FixedLenFeature([],tf.string),
  }
  return tf.io.parse_single_example(record, name_to_features)

def decode_record(record):
  aud = tf.io.decode_raw(
    record['snd'], out_type=tf.float64
  )
  return aud

for record in raw_dataset:
  parsed_record = parse_record(record)
  decoded_record = decode_record(parsed_record)
  aud = decoded_record
  print(aud.numpy()[0:10])
  print(train[0][0:10])
```

output:

```
[ 417.69951205 -231.58708746 -10.05624011 -146.10342256 -66.60317323
-159.91550792 -3.93602823 29.94517981 106.22196629 65.53008959]
[ 417.69951205 -231.58708746 -10.05624011 -146.10342256 -66.60317323
-159.91550792 -3.93602823 29.94517981 106.22196629 65.53008959]
```